# Explicit defining equations for del Pezzo surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, projective-varieties

Are there known explicit parametrizations of smooth del Pezzo surfaces, say of degree $5$ or higher, as surfaces cut out by equations in some projective space?

The closest I've been able to find is on p. 42 of ["Quantitative arithmetic of projective varieties" by Tim Browning](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0346-0129-0) (equation 2.21), where he describes a singular del Pezzo surface of degree $6$ by a system of $9$ quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^6$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a smooth degree $6$ del Pezzo can be described with coordinates $ b ,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6$ and equations $b a_i = a_{i-1}a_{i+1}$ for $i$ from $1$ to $6$ and $a_i a_{i+3} = b^2$ for $i$ from $1$ to $3$.

Comment: Equations for the degree 5 case are in https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.10715. Equations in a product of lines are in https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02984 section 3

Answer (score 3):

A smooth del Pezzo surface $X_d$ of degree $d\geq3$ has very ample anticanonical divisor $-K_X$. It is also the blowup $X\to \mathbb P^2$ in $k=9-d$ points $P_1,\ldots,P_k\in\mathbb{P}^2_{x,y,z}$ in general position, so we have that $-K_X=\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^2}(3) - E_1 - \cdots - E_k$. Therefore you can write down the anticanonical embedding of $X$ by writing down a basis for the linear system of cubic polynomials in $x,y,z$ that vanish at $P_1,\ldots,P_k$. For example if $d=6$ then, up to a linear automorphism of $\mathbb P^2$, we can assume that the three points we blow up are $(1:0:0)$, $(0:1:0)$ and $(0:0:1)$ and the seven-dimensional linear system of cubic polynomials vanishing at these points has a basis given by $xyz,x^2y,xy^2,y^2z,yz^2,xz^2,x^2z$, which are the coordinates $b,a_1,\ldots,a_6$ in Will Sawin's comment above. (This also follows from the description of $X_6$ as a toric variety.)

For each $d$ this will give you an embedding $X_d\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^d$ of codimension $d-2$ where the $X_d$ is cut out by quadratic polynomials. (For $X_9=\mathbb P^2$ it gives the third Veronese embedding.) However there are many simpler embeddings that one can work with if you want to work with explicit equations. For example $X_6$ can also be described as a smooth hypersurface of bidegree $(1,1,1)$ in $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$.

Comment: Possibly the OP wants to work over a non-algebraically closed field (the degree $6$ del Pezzo has a large automorphism group).

Comment: @JasonStarr I am indeed interested in how the construction would generalize to, say, $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, I want to take the points $P_1,...,P_k$ to be Galois conjugates over some number field of degree $k$. But this answer is a great starting point, especially the comments about the anticanonical embedding. Also to add, a discussion on the aforementioned automorphism group can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212015/automorphisms-of-del-pezzo-surfaces

Comment: "Therefore you can write down the anticanonical embedding of  by writing down a basis for the linear system of cubic polynomials in ,, that vanish at 1,…,." Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: In which direction do you want more explanation? Why it is true? Or how to do it?

Comment: What I don't understand is why this is true: why knowing that $-K_X=\pi^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(3)-E_1-\dots-E_k$ (which I understand) gives us the fact that we can write down the anticanonical embedding in that way.

Comment: The reason it is an embedding is that $-K_X$ is a very ample divisor class for $X$. (Not true if $k>6$.) The reason you can express it in terms of cubics like that follows from the standard formula for pulling back divisors after blowing up a smooth point on a surface.